# Learning VBA programming concepts

Tags: excel, vba

Which is the best book/any other source to master Programming in VBA Excel?

I have been working on excel recently and I really want to master it.Can you give suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I should say I can handle it pretty good.
I have been spend lots time forums example:

- http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/
- http://www.mrexcel.com/
- http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/

Here is a list of some books:

- http://www.mrexcel.com/articles.shtml
- http://www.datapigtechnologies.com/ExcelMain.htm
- http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/getstarted.htm

I hope this will help you

Comment: Thankyou so much. :)

Comment: Lemme me know if I can help you in the future with any questions :)